# System call for "cp" is modified unexpectedly

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to copy and rename a file using a system call to `cp`. The problem is that the command gets changed during the call and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
char *cp=(char*) malloc(100);
snprintf(cp,100,"%s%s%s","cp ~/.nanorc ~/.nanocfgmgr/",arg,"\0" );
printf("%s\n",cp);
system(cp);
free(cp);
```

Executing the string, which should look like `cp ~/.nanorc  ~/.nanocfgmgr/newfile`, directly in the terminal works as expected, but running the program yields `cp: cannot create regular file '/home/user/.nanocfgmgr/.nanocfgmgr/newfile`. I can't figure out why the directory gets duplicated.

EDIT: example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <argp.h>

struct parser_args{
    int argc;
    char **argv;
    int *nargs;
    char *path;

};
//where 'cp' is called
int parser(int key,char *arg, struct argp_state *state){
    switch(key){
        case 's': ;
            char *cp=(char*) malloc(100);
            snprintf(cp,100,"%s%s%s","cp ~/.nanorc  ~/.nanocfgmgr/",arg,"\0" );
            printf("arg = [[%s]]\n", arg); printf("cp = [[%s]]\n", cp);
            system(cp);
            free(cp);

    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char path[50]={};
    strcpy(path,strcat(getenv("HOME"),"/.nanocfgmgr"));    
    
    char cfg_path[50]={};    
    strcpy(cfg_path, path);
    strcat(cfg_path, "/configs.json");
    char *mkdir=(char*) malloc(50);
    strcpy(mkdir,"mkdir ");
    strcat(mkdir,path); 
    strcat(mkdir," > /dev/null 2>&1");
    system(mkdir);
    free(mkdir);

    struct argp_option options[]={
        {"save",'s',"NAME",0,"Backs up the configuration file Usage: nanocfgmr NAME [DESCRIPTION]"},
         {0}
    };

    struct argp argp={options,parser};
    struct parser_args *input= (struct parser_args*) malloc(sizeof(struct parser_args));
    return argp_parse(&argp,argc,argv,0,0,input);
}
```

Comment: Show [mcve] and the way you are invoking it

Comment: BTW, writing `"\0"` as a third `%s` is useless. Each string is supposed to be already terminated. If it is not the case with your `arg`, then it is your problem.

Comment: Print what's in `arg` as well as what's in `cp`.  The chances are that `arg` has the directory as well as the file name.  I prefer to see diagnostic printing identy what's printed better: `printf("arg = [[%s]]\n", arg); print("cp = [[%s]]\n", cp);` — that way, you can see unexpected trailing spaces, or newlines, or carriage returns, in the strings.

Comment: `arg` contains only the filename string, as i expected. `cp` doesn's seem to change before the system call. The added terminator is a result of me trying anything that came to mind. Running just the first snippet in isolation, after declaring an `arg` worked though.

Comment: Confusingly, a "system call" and a "call to the `system` function" are two completely different things.

Comment: Don't use arbitrary hardcoded buffer sizes for paths. There's `pathconf` for that.

Comment: BTW, using string concatenation to form a command passed to `system()` is a common cause of severe security bugs; it's an **extremely** bad idea. Better to use an `execv`-family call to directly invoke the desired binary with no shell in the way; that way if instead of `newfile` the name you're passed is `$(rm -rf ~)`, you avoid deleting the user's home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to

```
strcat(getenv("HOME"),"/.nanocfgmgr")
```

`getenv()` doesn't allocate a new string, it returns a pointer to the string in the environment array. When you concatenate to this, you're modifying the environment (you're probably also overwriting the environment variables that follow `HOME`).

When the shell processes a filename that begins with `~`, replaces that with the `HOME` environment variable variable. Since you've added `.nanocfgmgr` to this, your pathnames are expanded relative to that subdirectory.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/getenv.html) specifies that you shouldn't do this concatenation; it says:

> The application shall ensure that it does not modify the string pointed to by the `getenv()` function.

It ideally should be declared to return `const char *`, then the code won't compile, but there's probably historical reasons why it's not.

You can use `snprintf()` instead of `strcat()`, then you won't modify the environment.

```
snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s/.nanocfgmgr", getenv("HOME"));
```